# Change colour of overlay area when using Flyout in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am using a FlyoutBase in my UWP app. I have set the LightDismissOverlayMode Property to "On". This makes the area outside of the light-dismiss UI to be darkened. Is there any way by which I can choose the colour of the area being darkened?

Comment: Can you share some code please and try to better explain the question

Comment: Refer to the remarks section of this web page- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.lightdismissoverlaymode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_FlyoutBase_LightDismissOverlayMode. I wish to change the colour of the area which they describe as "overlay".

Comment: Does the following answer work?

Comment: Yes! I have accepted the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way by which I can choose the colour of the area being darkened?

There is `FlyoutLightDismissOverlayBackground` `StaticResource` in **generic.xaml** file, and you could modify it's `ResourceKey` for changing color in `Application.Resources` like the following.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <StaticResource x:Key="FlyoutLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlAcrylicElementMediumHighBrush" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```